# Long Applovin interstitial Ads shows as a two cycle so there is a loss in user retention

Tags: android, ads, applovin

I am using applovin ads in my android app, but the ads are too long and not able to click on the close as well.

The user experience is too bad. Also the ads are shown as tow cycles. It leads to the loss in user retention.

Kindly let me know any one facing the issue like the same.

I have followed this doc to show the interstitial ads in my app.

https://dash.applovin.com/documentation/mediation/android/getting-started/interstitials

Comment: Have a look at this article it might help https://support.applovin.com/hc/en-us/articles/17529730029837-Stop-unwanted-or-inappropriate-ads

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. May be you did it but if you don't someone also facing the same issue because I am also facing this issue. It is a bug in MaxAd in "testing Mode". You can check it while downloading from play store and on a real time device.

Comment: In the real time also we facing the same on the two cycles.

Comment: You should check your onCreate activity. You are trying to fininsh the activity and after closing the ad you cal it again. Make your app show only one time ad

Answer (score 0):

its easy to setting time in applovin, by going to discovery and Application go to video setting and adjust
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dTmi.png)
hope thats answer your question